Getting error for making build after updating Nodejs version in my ReactJs Project
I recenty updated my React Projects nodejs version from 14.16.1 to 20.11.1.
The issue is when I create a build using "yarn run build" command, it is failing and causing this error,
"Failed to compile.
Cannot assign to read only property 'stack' of object  
'JisonParserError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '0')'".

Due to this I am unable to make a build.
this is my scripts in package.json
"scripts": {
  "start": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider react-scripts start",
  "build": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build --prod",
  "winBuild": "set "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false" && react-scripts build",
  "test": "react-scripts test",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject",
  "pretty": "prettier --write './**/\*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,css,scss,md,json}' --config ./.prettierrc",
  "tslint-check": "tslint-config-prettier-check ./tslint.json",
  "tslint": "tslint -c tslint.json src/**/\*.{ts,tsx} --fix --format verbose",
  "start:prod": "yarn run build && serve -s build"
},

Can any one help me what the issue is as there is no file name suggesting in the cli where this issue is occuring.this is the screenshot of the error ocurring
I tried changing the scripts and searched for "stack" keyword in my project but there is no stack defined in the entire project files.
